# Automatic commit from server to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, cpanel, plesk

i'm studing bitbucket, it's possibile follow this flow?

1)developer upload file on server with ftp

2) with a cronjob the server commit & push changed files to  bitbucket

ps. i need a solution for plesk and cpanel

thank you!

Comment: in step 2 you are saying about svn but tag of question is git.  are you asking about svn or git?

Comment: i mean git, sorry

Comment: So yes what you want to do is possible. But your jobs tool (e.x. jenkins) should have write permissions to your bitbucket (some fake user).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, yes. But it's not recommended because you don't get meaningful commit messages, only automated ones, and the developer has little control over when to commit.

Comment: unfortunately not every company understands it and some even use such approach